# webpage requiring log in to view

Tags: php, security, authentication, user-controls

I am making a website and I want to make many pages of the website inaccessible unless you log in, just like facebook or emails services.

It will be a streaming website and will be database driven, so it must be flexible, so the use of the .htaccess and CGI processes are out of the question.

I heard that there are CMS managers but they take over everything and you cannot do anything except through them, which is something i do not want...  so i kept thinking for a while and came with a way which is to make the server check for log in, if no login found then  sends him to another page.
this peusedo code should make it easier to understand:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if ($_SESSION["islogged"] == no)
    { load some data and block some OR go to login page; }
?>
```

but the website will be charging for services and I do not want to risk any leaks, this idea was mine and i couldn't find anything on the web to help me with it, and i am not sure whether it is possible to create a fake session... i am planning to encrypt the session details anyway, but some facts here would help.

What i need to know is:

1. is this reliable? can it be bypassed?
2. is there another way which is better and more secure?

Comment: Fake session? I'd say go for it. This is what many folks do anyhow. They may put something different in the session but the technique is the same.

Comment: by fake session i mean injecting the session variable changing the value of $_SESSION["islogged"] so they'd be seen as logged in although  they didn't log in...  i do not know much about networking so i had to ask... and is there a way to improve this or a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On way of doing it is to set a user variable to the actual user from the database.

So when a user logs in

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $_user_record_from_database;

if($_SESSION['user']){
    //Do user logged in stuff
}else{
    //Do user not logged in stuff
}

//To log a user out just set $_SESSION['user'] = NULL
```

Comment: That is on mind... instead i will be using the ID for comments and other services purpose... i am more worried about the security implications... i doubt facebook or google use such a method... as a starter this will be good, but i have to be prepared incase since the service will be holding money and the money might become large, and with the online shopping services a bad security will ruin everything. my most worry is someone accessing an dev account somehow... how can i make this more secure other than encrypting the variables??

Comment: If you a building an online shopping why don't you just pick up something like opencart or magento. You can always build plugins for them. Trust me you are better off doing that. You sound like a beginner. Not trying to offend. These things are build by people with years of experience in PHP security and web security.

Good luck.

Comment: I am a beginner in PHP, but in any application security is important.. and as a proud programmer i cant keep using other people's securities and softwares.. I want to be able to make my own, only then I will feel comfortable using others... but for a serious work you are right. i guess i will have to do with whatever i have at the moment, but a tip would help since the website is not e-commerce only.. there will be some other services as well so i must secure my web server and pages.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not logged in and you encrypt the sessions when they do log in, this seems to be to be fairly secure.

However, I would actually suggest another approach all together. I know you avoided CMS platforms because of their control, but I would suggest Wordpress for this. You can create your own plugins, and with shortcodes make all kinds of magic happen on pages, and just let WP handle if they are logged in or not, and your plugins can use the WP is logged in function to show or not show things. This gives you total control, you can even create your own form for registration and call the WP register user function if you want.